# list all records for current week, day by day, also show day if no records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why is my each-do-block for jobs not interpretated? Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.1.7.

```
# _jobs.html.slim

tbody
  - (Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week).to_a.each do |day|
    h3= day.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    - Job.due_day(day).each do |job|
      <from here its ignored>
      tr= job.start_time
      tr= job.name
      ...


# job.rb

def self.due_day(day)
  all.select{|x| x.start_time.to_date == day}
end
```

Expected Output:

25.01.2016
26.01.2016
Job 1
27.01.2016
Job 2
28.01.2016
Job 3
Job 4
29.01.2016
30.01.2016

Current Output:

25.01.2016
26.01.2016
27.01.2016
28.01.2016
29.01.2016
30.01.2016
Job 1
Job 2
Job 3
Job 4

Comment: try to print due_day(day) .. like this :   puts "Due date(s) is " ; all.select{|x| x.start_time.to_date == day}    .. is there any? .... you may also wana raise an error if nil

Comment: What rails version is this?

Comment: Interesting: I had to read it up, but one can actually use `select` on a scope with a block! But this doesn't solve your problem ;) Could the problem be just within the HTML? You are emitting `<h3>` within `<tbody>`. Because according to your output, `due_date` seems to find the jobs just fine.

Comment: To me it looks like the `|day|` is looped through the `h3= day.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")`. After that it prints all jobs.

Comment: Your markup is invalid (tr elements should only contain td/th elements). That could easily make the browser do crazy stuff - check the actual html source

Answer (score 2):

One small addition to the answer of @mixan946:

```
def self.grouped_by_week_day
  today = Date.today
  where(start_time: today.beginning_of_week..today.end_of_week)
    .group_by { |job| job.start_time.to_date }
end

# make the call outside the loop in order to make the SQL query once.
- jobs_grouped_by_week_day = Jobs.grouped_by_week_day
- (Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week).each |day|
    h3= day.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    - next if jobs_grouped_by_week_day[day].blank?
    table
        - jobs_grouped_by_week_day[day].each do |job|
        <from here its ignored>
        tr:td= job.start_time
        tr:td= job.name
```

The difference is that iterating on a hash created with `group_by`, you don't get the keys of the hash which they don't have any values. So, my suggestion is to iterate through the days of the week that you are interested and access the hash by that day.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple issues in your code
tbody

```
# Doing in this way is very slow when you have noticeable amount of records
# it's responsibility of database to work with data
def self.due_day(day)
  all.select{|x| x.start_time.to_date == day}
end
```

I suggesting next solution:

```
def self.grouped_by_week_day
  today = Date.today
  # All type conversions handled by ActiveRecord 
  where(start_time: today.beginning_of_week..today.end_of_week)
    .group_by {|j| j.start_time.to_date }    
end

- Job.grouped_by_week_day do |day, jobs|
    h3= day.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    # It's better to not paste non-table related markup in tables
    # so leave h3 in outer of table
    table
      - jobs.each do |job|
        <from here its ignored>
        # To show cell use td, not tr
        tr:td= job.start_time
        tr:td= job.name
```